# Getting clip raster ERROR 1: Cutline feature without geometry?

Tags: qgis, raster, error-1

I am using QGIS 2.18.15. I tried clipping a raster

[image]

The mask layer is a shapefile. And it comes out as "ERROR 1: Cutline feature without a geometry"

I checked the point data that I interpolated and it's in the proper coordinate referencing system.

The intention is to clip the raster to the map at the back.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CRS != geometry - seems like your shapefile has a faulty geometry. Go to `vector -> geometry tools -> check validity` and repair any faults which show up.

Also try using `dissolve` in order to remove overlaps in the geometry.

Comment: I tried it, and all points came out as valid...

Comment: Wait... you're trying to clip a raster to points? Or do you mean it only turned out valid vertices?

Comment: im trying to clip a raster of points to a shapefile layer map... i tried doing it before and it worked but now the error comes out

Comment: Could you upload a small example for your "raster of points"? I can't imagine it right now.

Comment: please see edit above^ im very new here sorry

Comment: Did you use the same shapefile the last time? Because it seems to have multiple parts, which could be a source of error. Have you tried using "dissolve" on your shapefile/mask?

Comment: yes i used the same shapefile... the only thing i changed now was the raster file.. not sure what dissolve is...

Comment: Dissolve is a tool that takes multiple features and merges them into one. Use it to merge your polygons into a single polygon.